# Mockgoose: how to simulate a error in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to do unit test around a mongoose powered application.
While mockgoose does a great work at simulating mongoose so I can test around it, I didn t find a way to push it to fail a call, so I can test the error handling logic.

Is it a supported use case? Or should I find another framework?

Code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Test = {},
    Doc = require('./model/Doc.js');

var dbURL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/',
    dbName = 'Test';

function connect(callback) {
    Test = mongoose.createConnection(dbURL + dbName); //<-- Push this to fail
    Test.on('error', (err) => {
        callback(err);
    });
    Test.once('open', function () {
        callback();
    }); 
}
```

Test:

```
var chai = require('chai'),
    expect = chai.expect,
    util = require('util');

var config = require('./config.json');

var proxyquire =  require('proxyquire').noPreserveCache();
var sinon = require('sinon');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mockgoose = require('mockgoose');

describe('test', () => {
    describe('Connect', () => {
        beforeEach((callback) => {
            mockgoose(mongoose).then(() => {
                callback();
            });
        });

        it('Expect to connect to the database', (done) => {
            var stub = {
                    mongoose: mongoose
                },
                test = proxyquire('./../test.js', {
                    'mongoose': stub.mongoose
                });

            test.connect((err) => {
                try {
                    expect(err).to.not.be.ok;
                    done();
                } catch(err) {
                    done(err);
                }
            });

        it('Expect to throw error when failing to connect to the database', (done) => {
            var stub = {
                    mongoose: mongoose
                },
                medical = proxyquire('./../medical.js', {
                    'mongoose': stub.mongoose
                });

            medical.connect((err) => {
                try {
                    expect(err).to.be.ok;
                    done();
                } catch(err) {
                    done(err);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Result in:

```
Connect
      ✓ Expect to connect to the database
      1) Expect to throw error when failing to connect to the database


  1 passing (234ms)
  1 failing

  1) Medical Connect Expect to throw error when failing to connect to the database:
     AssertionError: expected undefined to be truthy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up stubing `mongoose.createConnection` (so the generator) to return a object which call the error.

```
            let stub = {
                mongoose: {
                    createConnection: () => {
                        return {
                            on: (eventName, callback) => {
                                if(eventName === 'error') {
                                    callback('Medical Error');
                                }
                            },
                            once: () => {}
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            medical = proxyquire('./../medical.js', {
                'mongoose': stub.mongoose
            });
```